# navigation in Android TV

Tags: android, listview, android-tv, smart-tv

navigation in Android TV.

How do I create just the navigation android tv. I do not care to use the entire theme, it provides android studio.
And I do not understand much of what is in the example given by android studio.
I understand that is something the String.
I looked on the internet examples, but right now, android tv has no further information at this time.

I'm interested only create menu navigation side, nothing more.

Thank you very much.
[image]

Comment: Are you interested in using the entire Leanback library? That would give you everything you need: the sidebar and navigation.

If not, then you could just override the onKeyDown method and update a cursor based on the user pressing up or down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a really nice tutorial : http://corochann.com/browsefragment-header-customization-android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-17-697.html

it shows you how to create a custom navigation side with an image and a text

Here what a tried in my application : 
copy his IconHeaderItem class and in your loadRows paste

```
IconHeaderItem gridItemPresenterHeader = new IconHeaderItem(0, BEWELL_THERMO, R.drawable.bewell_thermo);
    GridItemPresenter mGridPresenter = new GridItemPresenter();
    ArrayObjectAdapter gridRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(mGridPresenter);
    gridRowAdapter.add(DERNIERE_MESURE);
    gridRowAdapter.add(GRID_STRING_GUIDED_STEP_FRAGMENT);
    gridRowAdapter.add(GRID_STRING_RECOMMENDATION);
    gridRowAdapter.add(GRID_STRING_SPINNER);
    mGridItemListRow = new ListRow(gridItemPresenterHeader, gridRowAdapter);
    mRowsAdapter.add(mGridItemListRow);
    setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);
```

Comment: the given tutorial link is not valid showing page can't be found.

Comment: It s wierd cause it works fine for me. Anyways, I copy paste again. If it still doesn't try to access via the main home of that web site : http://corochann.com/. Click on this article BrowseFragment Header customization – Android TV application hands on tutorial 17

Comment: the idea is good, but there are many issues unanswered.
how to create a EditText, and many other questions unanswered.

Comment: you can add the Edit text. To do that, just modify the IconHeaderItemPresenter class and in the onBindViewHolder you can add you edit Text with EditText mEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mEditText);